Regex capture end value if line begins with
If i have data that is like
DAAR BR 37291 Y%oVol <0.001
Bil2 CH 382 %Mass 0.01
JOL BR 444489 Vol 44.4
TOME BR 37291 Y%oVol <0.005

I want to capture the end value for DAAR (<0.001) but no other line using REGEX that I can put into PAD.
I know that (\s\<\d\.\d*) will capture the <0.001 but I can't find a way to apply only to DAAR.
In short, what is between DAAR and <0.001 could be anything.

I don't know how automate desktop works but something like: DARR.*(<\d\.\d*) works with many regex flavours.

Sadly that gives me the entire line

In fact, it matches the whole line. But, you have the desired data in group 1. Another way to do the job (if supported) is DARR.*\K<\d\.\d*

If you don't want groups, you could use a lookbehind, but they're not supported everywhere: (?<=DAAR[^<]*?)<\d\.\d* only matches the first <0.001 after DAAR for example

Regular expressions in Power Automate are problematic. Also, while it can crop the text before the first occurrence of a space, it cannot crop the text after a last occurrence.
However, you can reverse the text, crop everything before the first space, then reverse that to get everything after the last space:
flow to crop text after last space
LOOP FOREACH CurrentItem IN FileContents
    Text.CropText.CropTextBeforeFlag Text: CurrentItem ToFlag: $'''%' '%''' IgnoreCase: False CroppedText=> CroppedText IsFlagFound=> IsFlagFound
    IF IsFlagFound = $'''true''' THEN
        IF CroppedText = $'''%'DAAR'%''' THEN
            Text.Reverse Text: CurrentItem ReversedText=> ReversedItem
            Text.CropText.CropTextBeforeFlag Text: ReversedItem ToFlag: $'''%' '%''' IgnoreCase: False CroppedText=> CroppedReversedText IsFlagFound=> IsFlagFound
            IF IsFlagFound = $'''true''' THEN
                Text.Reverse Text: CroppedReversedText ReversedText=> CroppedText
                Display.ShowMessageDialog.ShowMessage Title: $'''Cropped Text''' Message: CroppedText Icon: Display.Icon.None Buttons: Display.Buttons.OK DefaultButton: Display.DefaultButton.Button1 IsTopMost: False ButtonPressed=> ButtonPressed
            END
        END
    END
END

Note you will have to get the file or list into FileContents first, and you might want to output CroppedText to a file instead of displaying it.
